# JQuery - How to insert element after parent element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to find if an element is on the page. If the element is on the page then find its parent element and insert it after that parent element.

JQuery:

```
if($('.underline .catIcon').length > 0){
    $('.underline .catIcon').each(function(){
       $(this).insertAfter($(this).parent().find('h2')); 
       $(this).css('float','left');
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<h2 class="underline">
  <div class="catIcon" style="padding-right: 10px;"><!-- element to move -->
    <img class="catIcon" alt="Projects" src="http://www.example.com/storage/images/category/on-site-support56x56.jpg" style="float: left;">
  </div>
  Projekty
</h2>
<!-- here before text and after h2 tag with class underline -->.text
<a class="link2 ui-link" target="_blank" href="http://www.example.com/cz/cs/22.html">>> info</a>
```

Comment: `div` inside `h2` element?

Comment: `.underline .catIcon` means `div` under `.underline` or `image`? Because `image` and `div` both having `catIcon class`

Comment: You only wrote that it didn't work. I deleted that. Usually, exact descriptions of the problem help others find a solution for you.

Comment: @Mark I don't know what should I put in description to be more understandable for U.

Comment: This isn't about being understandable for me only. You already got your answer, so it probably isn't too important this time, but whenever you ask a question here, you should write exactly what you want to happen and what is happening instead. Not only that "it doesn't work" because such a statement has no meaning for the people who try to help. Please, keep this in mind, next time when you ask a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `h2` is the parent's parent element, so you need to use `.closest('h2')`, not `.parent().find('h2')` - it looks for a `h2` element inside the image's parent(`div`)

```
jQuery(function(){
    $('.underline .catIcon').each(function () {
        $(this).insertAfter($(this).closest('h2'));
        $(this).css('float', 'left');
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/AU5m6/)

Answer (score 0):

use **[closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)**

you need to go parent `.underline` then don't find in this

```
 if($('.underline .catIcon').length > 0){
        $('.underline .catIcon').each(function(){
           $(this).insertAfter($(this).closest(".underline")); 
           $(this).css('float','left');
        });
    }
```